# Misunderstanding about Comparator in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Pair<>("1", 8));
        list.add(new Pair<>("3", 2));
        list.add(new Pair<>("2", 15));

        list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.v))
            .map(p -> p.k)
            .forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}

class Pair<K, V> {
    K k;
    V v;
    public Pair(K k, V v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }
}
```

Ok, as you understood this code is printing my pair keys from the lowest value associated to the highest so I get the expected output:

3
1
2

So far so good. Now I wanted to do the reverse, I thought I would only have to do

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.v).reversed())
    .map(p -> p.k)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But I get a compilation error:

```
v cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

So it seems like `comparingInt` is returning a `Comparator<Object>`. Why it so? Shouldn't it return a `Comparator<Integer>` ?

These are both reproductible with Eclipse Luna version 1 and javac.

```
javac -version => 1.8.0
java  -version => java version "1.8.0_25"
```

Oh also feel free to change the title of my question is you find it too general, but I couldn't find the correct terms

Comment: It will probably work with Comparator.reverseOrder.

Comment: @assylias Well how would I achieve that with reverseOrder? It would mean that my pair objects are already comparable.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172595/comparator-reversed-not-compiles-using-lambda

Comment: @RobertBain Exaclty what I was looking for. Thanks =) You can close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's just that type inference is failing, basically - because the `reverse()` call gets in the way of the expected argument type of `sorted()` and the lambda expression.

You can do it if you specify the type to `comparingInt` explicitly:

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.<Pair<String, Integer>>comparingInt(p -> p.v).reversed())
    .map(p -> p.k)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or if you just declare the comparer first:

```
Comparator<Pair<String, Integer>> forward = Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.v);
list.stream()
    .sorted(forward.reversed())
    .map(p -> p.k)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It feels to me like there should be a `Stream.reverseSorted` so make this sort of thing really easy, but it doesn't look like it exists :(

Comment: ... which is quite ugly, then I prefer use `sorted((p1, p2) -> p2.v.compareTo(p1.v))`. So it's likely a bug in the compiler?

Comment: @user2336315: I agree it's ugly - but that doesn't mean it's a bug in the compiler. I believe it's a limitation of the type inference in the language, which isn't the same thing. To be honest, I've never fully understood how generic type inference in Java works (and I believe it's changed in a few places over time) - but this definitely feels like a simple limitation to me.

Comment: Ah I see. Maybe in a future release, this will be improved. I know they have alreay done some improvments so that's why I found it was weird that it didn't compile... :(

Comment: As @RobertBain pointed in out it has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25173599/2336315. I'll accept your answer since it provides a decent workaround.

Comment: @user2336315: I'm glad Robert's answer was similar to mine :)

Comment: Well it's not his answer actually, but the answer + the comment of Brian Goetz provides a really nice explanation :-)

Comment: @user2336315 Actually, that other question even gives you a better workaround - using method reference instead of lambda.

Comment: @Eran Yes but is not always applicable, for example if you want to sort map entries. By that I mean, if you have a `Map<String, List>` and you want to sort by the size of the list for example, its not possible with method reference.

Comment: Not a bug in the compiler.  Type inference will never be perfect; it has intrinsic limitations, and the harder we push it, the more surprising the effects when its limits are exceeded.  That said, I'll also point out that you can get the same effect with an explicitly typed lambda, which is slightly less clunky than explicit type witnesses in the generic method call.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/26883991/2711488 In other words, while type inference fails for method chaining it does work with nested method invocations. So instead of `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.v).reversed()` you can use `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.v))` That’ll work…