# comparing and thenComparing gives compile error

Tags: java, java-8, comparator, comparable

I am trying to sort `List` of employees by name then age using Java8 `Comparator`, I have created below `Comparator` but it gives me a compiler error

> `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<Object> to <unknown>`

```
    Comparator<String> c = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.split("\\s+")[0])
            .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+")[1])); //compile error
```

but it works if I explicitly specify the Type

```
    Comparator<String> c = Comparator.<String, String> comparing(s -> s.split("\\s+")[0])
            .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+")[1])); //works
```

or by creating two `Compartor`s and chain

```
    Comparator<String> name = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.split("\\s+")[0]);
    Comparator<String> age = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+")[1]));
    Comparator<String> cc = name.thenComparing(age); //works
```

I have specified the type `Comparator<String>` on the left side but why auto type inference is not finding the correct Type and expecting to specify explicitly.

Could someone clarify on this?

Here is the code

```
    String[] arr = { "alan 25", "mario 30", "alan 19", "mario 25" };
    Comparator<String> c = Comparator.<String, String> comparing(s -> s.split("\\s+")[0])
            .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+")[1]));
    List<String> sorted = Arrays.stream(arr).sorted(c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sorted);
```

output

```
[alan 19, alan 25, mario 25, mario 30]
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on generic type inference, but I'm guessing this is just "too much auto-inference".  Probably, it can't figure out the type of the `comparing()` method since it doesn't have any type to "anchor" it to, unlike the chaining method where you explicitly give a type to the result of `comparing()`.  Regardless, I think it would be more readable to write your own `Comparator`, and only call `split` once.  There's no prize for squeezing code into the fewest possible lines.

Comment: Target typing doesn’t work through chained method invocations, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28834656/2711488) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26883991/2711488) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31383947/2711488). However, you can simply use `Comparator.comparing(s -> s.replaceFirst("\\s+", " "))` instead of your two stage comparator and the outcome will be the same…

Comment: `Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.split("\\s+")[0]).thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+")[1]))` works but why this `String` is required, it can infer from `Comparator<String>`, is it a limitation in type inference ? BTW using `java version "1.8.0_60"`

Comment: @Holger, I’m not sure I got that. Your one-stage comparator would work nicely if all ages were guaranteed to be 2 digits, but I believe it would sort `[alan 102, alan 25, alan 8]` into this order, which is the opposite of the desired — am I right?

Comment: And thanks, @Holger, for the very useful links to the other places where you have excellently explained the stuff.

Comment: @Ole V.V.: indeed, it’s a deficiency of the chosen example, that doesn’t show numbers not having two digits, but I still would recommend to avoid the duplicated `split` operation and implement it as a single comparator, even if it gets more complex due to the number parsing. For larger lists, it might be even more efficient to convert all elements to a `(String,int)` type first, sort them, and convert them back to the `String` form…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java needs to know a type of all variables. In many lambdas it can infer a type, but in your first code snippet, it cannot guess the type of `s`. I think the standard way to solve that problem would be to declare it explicitly:

```
    Comparator<String> c = Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.split("\\s+")[0])
            .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+")[1]));
```

If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25501226/5772882), it has a similar type declaration in the argument to `Comparator.comparing()`.

Your method, explicitly giving the type arguments of `comparing()`, obviously works too (`Comparator.<String, String>comparing(…)`). The type arguments are also called *type witnesses*.

For your other method, declaring two comparators, I am pretty confident that in this case Java can infer from the `String` on the left side of the assignment, just as in the conventional `List <String> = new ArrayList<>();`. When you go on to call `thenComparing()` in the same expression, Java can no longer see that the type from the left side is relevant. It would be a bit like `int size = new ArrayList<>().size();` This works too:

```
    Comparator<String> name = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.split("\\s+")[0]);
    Comparator<String> c = name.thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+")[1]));
```

Comment: @ole-v-v Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.split("\\s+")[0]).thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+")[1])) works but why this String is required, it can infer from Comparator<String>, is it a limitation in type inference ? BTW using java version "1.8.0_60"

Comment: How do you infer that? You know that `thenComparing()` should return a `Comparator<String>` (to fit the left-hand side of the assignment), therefore `comparing()` needs to return `Comparator<String>`, therefore `s` needs to be a `String`. The compiler does not go through this many steps of reasoning. Yes, it’s a limitation in type inference, but I think it’s a limitation introduced on purpose because otherwise the rules would get too complicated and programmers would not understand them. This is my best guess.

Comment: The biggest problem is, that target typing through chained invocations could change the available methods for the subsequent invocation, which was actually used for determining the previous’ target type, i.e. with `foo(x).bar(y)`, the return type of `foo(x)` determines whether and which `bar(…)` methods are available, but applying target typing to `foo(x)` depends on the actually chosen `bar(…)` method.

Comment: I’m quite sure that this restriction will be lifter some day, but possibly only when the base type doesn’t change, i.e `Comparator.comparing` always returns a `Comparator`, target typing would only affect its type parameter, and the subsequently chained method is not overloaded, which is the case for `thenComparingInt`.

Comment: Another option is to use so-called *type witness* by adding a parameter to the first method call: `Comparator.<String>comparing()`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Your comment should be the actual answer.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Correct. That option is already mentioned in the question (which my answer mentions) (it should be `Comparator.<String, String>comparing(...)`; `comparing()` requires two type arguments, not one).

Comment: @Edward Alexander’s option is already mentioned in the question.