# How to sort an array of strings (in the form of names concatenated with numbers) in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, comparator

In case, I have an array of strings in the following format -

> ["synthia 16", "alicia 3", "alicia 2", "alicia 1", "synthia 2"]

The list is to be sorted by name first and then the following number. The output of sorting should be-

> ["alicia 1", "alicia 2", "alicia 3", "synthia 2", "synthia 16"]

I used comaparator to do this using Java:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortList {

public static void main ( String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"synthia 16", "alicia 4", "alicia 19", "alicia 1", "synthia 2"};
    System.out.println("Unsorted list:\n ");        
    displayList(names);

    Arrays.sort(names, new nameComparator());
    System.out.println("\nSorted list:\n");
    displayList(names);
}

public static void displayList(String[] names) {
    for(String name:names) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

private static class nameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] s1NameNumPair = s1.split(" ");
        String[] s2NameNumPair = s2.split(" ");
        if (s1NameNumPair[0].compareTo(s2NameNumPair[0]) > 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (s1NameNumPair[0].compareTo(s2NameNumPair[0]) < 1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            Double n1 = Double.parseDouble(s1NameNumPair[1]);
            Double n2 = Double.parseDouble(s2NameNumPair[1]);
            if (n1 > n2) { return 1; }
            else if (n1 < n2) { return -1; }
            else { return 0; }                
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, using comparator like this only sorts the array alphabetically by the name. Here's the output this code generates:

```
Unsorted list:

synthia 16
alicia 4
alicia 19
alicia 1
synthia 2

Sorted list:

alicia 1
alicia 19
alicia 4
synthia 2
synthia 16
```

How can I get the right sorted output?

Comment: Related: [comparing and thenComparing gives compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500280/comparing-and-thencomparing-gives-compile-error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must check for `> 0` and `< 0` so that `== 0` will go to else, 
try below

```
if (s1NameNumPair[0].compareTo(s2NameNumPair[0]) > 0) {
    return 1;
} else if (s1NameNumPair[0].compareTo(s2NameNumPair[0]) < 0) {
    return -1;
} else {
    Double n1 = Double.parseDouble(s1NameNumPair[1]);
    Double n2 = Double.parseDouble(s2NameNumPair[1]);
    return n1.compareTo(n2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `nameComparator` to this:

```
private static class nameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] s1NameNumPair = s1.split(" ");
        String[] s2NameNumPair = s2.split(" ");
        int diff = s1NameNumPair[0].compareTo(s2NameNumPair[0]);

        if (0 == diff) {
            Double n1 = Double.parseDouble(s1NameNumPair[1]);
            Double n2 = Double.parseDouble(s2NameNumPair[1]);

            return n1.compareTo(n2);
        }

        return diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this worked. Could you also explain how this is different from what I implemented? It seems to be doing the same thing. Let me know what I missed.

Comment: In the `if` and `else if` statements, it should be compared to 0.
There is already existing `compareTo()` method of String and Double that returns int.
So you don't have to compare again the value returned by this method.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the comparison as below.

```
private static class nameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] s1NameNumPair = s1.split(" ");
        String[] s2NameNumPair = s2.split(" ");
        if (s1NameNumPair[0].compareTo(s2NameNumPair[0]) > 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (s1NameNumPair[0].compareTo(s2NameNumPair[0]) < 0) { //here it should be <0 not <1
            return -1;
        } else {
            Double n1 = Double.parseDouble(s1NameNumPair[1]);
            Double n2 = Double.parseDouble(s2NameNumPair[1]);
            if (n1 > n2) {
                return 1;
            } else if (n1 < n2) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comparator like this :

1. Java 7

   ```
   Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
       String[] strings1 = o1.split("\\s+");
       String[] strings2 = o2.split("\\s+");
       int firstCompare = strings1[0].compareTo(strings2[0]);
       int secondCompare = Integer.valueOf(strings1[1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(strings2[1]));

       return firstCompare*2 + secondCompare;
   }
   ```

   };
2. Java 8

   ```
   Comparator<String> comparator =
   (String o1, String o2)-> {
       String[] strings1 = o1.split("\\s+");
       String[] strings2 = o2.split("\\s+");
       int firstCompare = strings1[0].compareTo(strings2[0]);
       int secondCompare = Integer.valueOf(strings1[1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(strings2[1]));

       return firstCompare*2 + secondCompare;
   };
   ```