# How do I get Comparator.comparing to correctly infer type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

public class Sorter {
    private List<Pair<Long, NameDTO>> dtoPairs = new ArrayList<>();

    public Sorter() {
        Comparator<Pair<Long, NameDTO>> bySize = Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft);
        Comparator<Pair<Long, NameDTO>> byName = Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getRight().getName());
        dtoPairs.sort(bySize.reversed().thenComparing(byName));
    }
}

class NameDTO {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This compiles with no problems. However, if I try to inline the variables like this:

```
 dtoPairs.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getLeft).reversed().thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getRight().getName())));
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
Sorter.java:[18,51] incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      method getLeft in class org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair<L,R> cannot be applied to given types
        required: no arguments
        found: java.lang.Object
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

How can I write this expression to make Java understand the parameters correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing and thenComparing gives compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500280/comparing-and-thencomparing-gives-compile-error)

Comment: @OleV.V.: I don't think that is a duplicate, it doesn't have the generic method reference which is what threw me off here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler the type of the generic parameters.
Try this:

```
dtoPairs.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(Pair<Long, NameDTO>::getLeft)
    .reversed()
    .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getRight().getName())));
```

Comment: Ah, cool, I hadn't seen that method reference syntax. The `(Pair<Long, NameDTO>) p` is apparently not needed, all I needed was the `Pair<Long, NameDTO>::getLeft` adjustment.

Comment: Right. I just added it so that it´s more clear. I removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This statement compiles just fine:

```
dtoPairs.sort(Comparator.comparing((Pair<Long, NameDTO> p) -> p.getLeft())
                        .reversed()
                        .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getRight().getName())));
```

...which points out the reason why yours doesn't compile: When you do the method reference (`Pair:getLeft`), `Pair` is raw and its type parameters are simply ignored. This makes the `thenComparing(...)` method to expect a `Comparator<Pair, Object>`.