# Is there any difference between these two codes?

Tags: java

```java
@Autowired
private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

public void test(String key) {
    // IDEA prompts an error
    Map<String, String> entries1 = stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash().entries(key);
        
    // This is OK.
    HashOperations<String, String, String> opsForHash = stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash();
    Map<String, String> entries = opsForHash.entries(key);  
}
```

Comment: What error was shown? Can you please post the error message?

Comment: Required type: Map <String, String>
Provided: Map <Object, Object>

Comment: @张善庆 That should be edited into your question.

Comment: That means `stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash().entries(key)` returns a `Map<Object, Object>` but you have initialized `entries1` as a `Map<String, String>` ==> type mismatch

Comment: What type is `stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash()`?

Comment: @deHaar But why `stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash();` retrun a `HashOperations<String, Object, Object>`, but I am initialized opsForHash as a `HashOperations<String, String, String>` is OK

Comment: Similar: [comparing and thenComparing gives compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500280/comparing-and-thencomparing-gives-compile-error)

Answer (score 4):

The problem Is that the method `opsForHash()` uses 2 generics, This is the signature:

```java
public <HK, HV> HashOperations<K, HK, HV> opsForHash()
```

If you want to use a single line, you need to set the generics, just like:

```java
Map<String, String> entries1 = stringRedisTemplate.<String, String>opsForHash().entries(key);
```

In your code, the second approach works because the compiler finds out the generics from the defined variable on the left side of the `=` operator.