# How to use Comparator in java with lambda expression?

Tags: java, comparator

I am using lambda expression to sort 2D array based on multiple column but it failed while compiling.

```
public static void 2DarraySort(int[][] box) {
    Arrays.sort(box, Comparator.comparingInt(row -> row[0]).thenComparingInt(row -> row[1]));
}
```

Can someone please tell what wrong I am doing?

Error message:

```
array required, but java.lang.Object found
```

Comment: Hello, can you show us the stack trace please?

Comment: @0009laH what stack trace? They say it failed while *compiling*.

Comment: See [comparing and thenComparing gives compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500280/comparing-and-thencomparing-gives-compile-error)

Answer (score 0):

This would work fine if you have not chained the comparators:

```java
Arrays.sort(box, Comparator.comparingInt(row -> row[0]));
```

However, when comparators are chained, the type of the objects being compared need to be specified explicitly, which may be done in two ways:

1. Provide type in `comparingInt/comparing`

```java
Arrays.sort(box, Comparator
    .<int[]>comparingInt(row -> row[0])
    .thenComparingInt(row -> row[1])
);
```

2. Specify `row` type in lambda:

```java
Arrays.sort(box, Comparator
    .comparingInt((int[] row ) -> row[0])
    .thenComparingInt(row -> row[1])
);
```