# Why doesn't this Java 8 stream example compile?

Tags: java, java-8, type-inference, java-stream

I'm trying to figure out why this code does not compile on JDK `1.8.0_45`:

```
public class Example<E extends Example<E>> {
    public List<? extends Example<?>> toExamples(Collection<String> collection) {
        return collection.stream()
                .map(v -> lookup(v))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <E extends Example<E>> E lookup(String value) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Adding a seemingly unnecessary cast fixes it:

```
public class Example<E extends Example<E>> {
    public List<? extends Example<?>> toExamples(Collection<String> collection) {
        return collection.stream()
                .map(v -> (Example<?>) lookup(v))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <E extends Example<E>> E lookup(String value) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the error from the compiler:

```
Example.java:9: error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
                      ^
  equality constraints: List<Object>
  upper bounds: List<? extends Example<?>>,Object
where R,A,T are type-variables:
  R extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
  A extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
  T extends Object declared in interface Stream
```

For some reason, the return type of `lookup()` isn't correctly inferred to something extending `Example`.

Comment: out of curiousity, did it compile on any previous versions of Java 8? this report seems awfully relevant: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077304

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: You can also change the signature of lookup: `public static <E extends Example<E>> Example<E> lookup(String value)`

Comment: Yet another instance of generic methods which claim to return whatever the caller wishes…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Peter Lawrey pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30599906/2711488), `? extends Example<?>` is not compatible with `E extends Example<E>`. Still, even fixing the signature doesn’t make type inference work here.

The reason is a known limitation of the type inference as it does not back-propagate through chained method invocations. In other words, the return type allows to infer the types for the `collect(…)` invocation but not for the preceding `map(…)` invocation. (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883991/2711488))

But it works for *nested* method invocations, so the following rewritten method can be compiled:

```
public class Example<E extends Example<E>> {
    public <E extends Example<E>> List<E> toExamples(Collection<String> collection) {
        return collection.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.mapping(v -> lookup(v), Collectors.toList()));
    }

    public static <E extends Example<E>> E lookup(String value) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Still, you have to rethink the semantics of your code. A method’s type parameter which appears only at the return type can’t be correct as it implies that “*whatever the caller substitutes for this type parameter, the method will return the right thing*”. Since the method implementation doesn’t know what the caller assumes, this is impossible. Only returning `null` or an empty list will work correctly, which is of little use.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix it this way. Note that the actual issue did have a `Class<? extends Example<?>>` parameter in the `toExamples()` method, and a `Class<E>` parameter in the `lookup()` method. So I'm afraid I oversimplified the problem.

Comment: Then, with an input parameter of type `Class<E>` which you pass through, the type inference should also work with a chained `.map(…).collect(…)` invocation.

Answer (score 9):

When you have a `?` it doesn't equal another `?`  i.e. the compiler doesn't see

```
? extends Example<?>
```

as a match for

```
E extends Example<E>
```

as it cannot assume the two `?` are the same. It could be

```
A extends Example<B>
```

When you perform the cast, you obscure the constraint so it can match.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the generic type defined in the static method is not the same as the generic type defined in the class.  You should be able to make the `lookup` method non-static so it matches the same type defined in the class level generic declaration:

```
    public E lookup(String value) {
        return null;
    }
```