# Why doesn't Stream#reduce implicitly accept an accumulative function handling super type elements?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, type-inference

Considering these classes and accumulation function, which represent a simplification of my original context (yet reproducing the same problem):

```
abstract static class Foo {
    abstract int getK();
}
static class Bar extends Foo {
    int k;
    Bar(int k) { this.k = k; }
    int getK() { return this.k; }
}

private static Foo combined(Foo a1, Foo a2) {
    return new Bar(a1.getK() + a2.getK());
}
```

I have attempted to perform an accumulation of items (originally data indexing reports) by relying on a separate function, `combined`, which deals directly with elements of type `Foo`.

```
Foo outcome = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
        .map(Bar::new)
        .reduce((a,b) -> combined(a, b))
        .get();
```

It turns out that this code results in a compilation error (OpenJDK "1.8.0_92"): *"Bad return type in lambda expression: Foo cannot be converted to Bar"*. The compiler insists on attempting to reduce the stream using `Bar` as the accumulative element, even when there is `Foo` as a common type for both the arguments to the cumulative function and its return type.

I also find peculiar that I can still take this approach as long as I explicitly map the stream into a stream of `Foo`s:

```
Foo outcome = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
        .<Foo>map(Bar::new)
        .reduce((a,b) -> combined(a, b))
        .get();
```

Is this a limitation of Java 8's generic type inference, a small issue with this particular overload of `Stream#reduce`, or an intentional behaviour that is backed by the Java specification? I have read a few other questions on SO where type inference has "failed", but this particular case is still a bit hard for me to grasp.

Comment: there is a conflict between the inferred type form the assignation, and the inferred type from the argument of `map` to determine the type of the stream. I assume Java would take the most specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is related to the reason why a list of `Derived` is not a list of `Base`. By doing `.map(Bar::new)` you create a stream of `Bar`. It is obviously not trivially convertible to stream of `Foo` according to the general rule “If `B` is an `A`, then `X<B>` is *not* `X<A>`”.

Then you're trying to `reduce` it, but `reduce` must create a stream of exactly the same type. What you want is `reduce` behaving like both `reduce` and `map` in the sense that you want it both reduce the stream to a single instance *and* change its type. This is more like a job for `collect` (except that `collect` works with mutable types).

But there is a variant of `reduce` that can change the type. And its signature actually gives us a hint of why the simple overload can't change the type of the stream:

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

It takes *two* functions! Why? Because Java streams are parallelizible. So a stream can perform reduction by parts and then combine parts into a single value. Here it is possible because we give an additional `combiner`. In your case one function is supposed to act as both accumulator and combiner which creates all the confusion about what exactly is its signature.

So the reason it doesn't work is because that overload lacks combiner that could combine partial results. Of course it isn't a “hard” reason in the sense that since `Foo` is a superclass of `Bar`, it is technically possible to use the same thing as both accumulator and combiner, like you do in your example with explicit `<Foo>`.

So it looks like a design decision that is intended to avoid possible confusion because of a stream randomly changing types after reduction. If you really want it, there is that another overload, but its signature is ugly enough to make the type change obvious just from looking at the code.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you're definitely creating a `BinaryOperator<Foo>` - you have to be, as you're returning a `Foo`. If you change `combined()` to be declared to return `Bar` (while still *accepting* `Foo`) then you'd be fine. It's the fact that the return type is tied to the input type that's the problem - it can't be either covariant or contravariant, because it's used for input *and* output.

To put it another way - you're expecting `reduce((a, b) -> combined(a, b))` to return an `Optional<Foo>`, right? So that suggests that you're expecting the `T` of the `reduce()` call to be `Foo` - which means that it should be operating on a `Stream<Foo>`. A `Stream<Bar>` only has a single-parameter `reduce` method that takes a `BinaryOperator<Bar>`, and your lambda expression using `combined` simple *isn't* a `BinaryOperator<Bar>`.

Another alternative is to add a cast to the lambda expression:

```
Foo outcome = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
    .map(Bar::new)                
    .reduce((a,b) -> (Bar)combined(a, b))
    .get();
```

Comment: I understand that changing the return type would also work. But in this case I wished to deal with `Foo`'s. The main matter of concern is why `reduce` couldn't accept a binary operator of `Foo` in the first place when using a `Stream<T>` where `T extends Foo`.

Comment: @E_net4: Because it accepts a `BinaryOperator<T>`, and your lambda expression can't be converted to a `BinaryOperator<Bar>` as it is.

Comment: @E_net4: In short, I think you're going to just have to accept it in the end. This *could* have been different if `reduce` had been designed to accept a `BiFunction<T, T, R>` for example.

Comment: Hah, so this could indeed work with a change of design in `reduce`, isn't it? That point is relevant to my question. :)

Comment: @E_net4: Thinking about it more, the problem is that you need to maintain the T between reductions. Have a look at the other overloads for example, and think about what reduce has to do. (I think I was wrong about saying it could just take a BiFunction. It's possible that it could take a `BinaryOperator<U>` with `U super T` but I can't check right now.)

Answer (score 5):

## Update

The simple answer to your question is that your reduce takes a `BinaryOperator<Bar>`, which says you must pass in a function that takes in two `Bar` values and returns a `Bar`.  Your lambda accepts two `Bar` parameters just fine, because your `combined` function sees that `Bar` is assignable to `Foo`.  For the return type however, the thinking goes in the opposite direction; while for the parameters you are concerned that the values passed in match your function, for the return type, you have to worry about whether the caller of your function can accept the type your function returns.  Because your function returns `Foo`, and the receiver is expecting a `Bar`, there is a compiler error, for the same reason that this fails:

```
Bar b = new Foo(1);
```

Adding the cast works, but it is unsafe, for the same reason that

```
Bar b  = (Bar) new Foo(1);
```

works but isn't safe -- not every instance of `Foo` will necessarily be a `Bar`.

There is a safe way to do the reduction, without casts, using the 3-parameter reduce. It lets you reduce to a different type than the stream type.

```
Foo combined = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
            .map(Bar::new)
            .reduce(
                new Bar(0),                       // starting value, type Foo
                (Foo a, Bar b) -> combined(a, b), // apply each Bar to create new Foo 
                (Foo a, Foo b) -> combined(a,b)); // combine intermediate results if parallel
```

The first parameter, `(Foo)new Bar(0)` is the initial value to seed the reduction, and will be the value returned if the stream is empty.

The second parameter folds in each `Bar` from the `Stream` into a new accumulated `Foo` value.

The third parameter, used chiefly in parallel streams, combines two intermediate accumulated `Foo` values.

The `combine` function works for both the accumulator and combiner only because `Bar` happens to be assignable to `Foo`.

Note that, as was mentioned in the comments, this can be written more succinctly because, in this case, the Stream element type is assignable to the Accumulator type, so it can be simplified to

```
Foo combined = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
            .map(Bar::new)
            .reduce(new Bar(0), (a,b) -> combined(a, b), (a, b) -> combined(a,b));
```

Or

```
Foo combined = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
            .map(Bar::new)
            .reduce(new Bar(0), MyClass::combined, MyClass::combined);
```

Comment: you don't need to cast a Bar into a Foo. `U` should be inferred from the assigned type

Comment: Thanks, @njzk2. I was trying to show what types were required, and `new Bar(0)` by itself seemed misleading to me -- It's `Foo` that is required, and not every situation will have a U assignable to T.  I'll update my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed hitting a limitation of Java 8’s type inference. In one sentence, target typing doesn’t work for the *receiver* of a method invocation. So in your code, you have an invocation of the method `reduce` on the result of `Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).map(Bar::new)`, which makes that expression the receiver of the method invocation `.reduce((a,b) -> combined(a, b))` which can’t use any information about what `reduce` might expect.

Instead, the type of the expression `Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)`, which is the receiver of the `.map` invocation, and the argument `Bar::new` are the only information to determine the type of the resulting Stream and there is nothing suggesting that `Stream<Foo>` could be the better choice compared with `Stream<Bar>`.

It’s the same issue as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173599/2711488) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883991/2711488).

It can be easily demonstrated how it would work, if type inference was possible, by dissolving the method invocations:

```
Stream<Foo> s= Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).map(Bar::new);
Foo outcome = s.reduce((a,b) -> combined(a, b)).get();
```

which works smoothly.

Besides providing an explicit type for `map` as with `.<Foo>map(Bar::new)`, there’s also the alternative

```
Optional<Foo> outcome =
    Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
    .map(Bar::new)
    .collect(Collectors.reducing((a,b) -> combined(a, b)));
```

This works because `collect` on a `Stream<T>` allows an argument of type `Collector<? super T,…>` so the compiler can infer `Collector<Foo,…>` from the expected target type which is valid for invoking `collect` on a `Stream<Bar>`. However, you can’t chain a `get()` call to get the `Foo` immediately, for the same reason described above; the target type won’t be supplied to the receiver of the method invocation.