# Java type inference confusion

Tags: java-8, java-stream, type-inference, collectors, functional-interface

Can someone explain this to me, why does not this expression type get automatically inferred by the compiler ?

`Stream.empty().collect(Collectors.summingInt(CharSequence::length))`

We know that `CharSequence::length` in this context is a `ToIntFunction<CharSequence>`, so the type being consumed from the stream elements is a `CharSequence`, therefore, the stream being collected is of type `Stream<CharSequence>`.

On my IDE, I get the following error :

> The method collect(Collector<? super Object,A,R>) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#1-of ?,Integer>)

As you can see from the error message, the `Stream.empty()` gets auto inferred to a `Stream<Object>` which is definitely not what I want !

Comment: This is a known limitation. The target type is not propagated through *chained* method invocations. Here, `Stream.empty()` and `collect(Collectors.summingInt(CharSequence::length))` are chained. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883991/2711488) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173599/2711488).

Answer (score 4):

Java's `Stream.empty()` is a generic method with the following declaration.

```
public static<T> Stream<T> empty() {
   // Remainder omitted.
}
```

So you have to pass the type parameters explicitly. Otherwise it will create a `Stream` of type `java.lang.Object`. So change your declaration like so to get rid of the error.

```
Stream.<CharSequence>empty().collect(Collectors.summingInt(CharSequence::length));
```

Java won't infer the type based on data types used in downstream operations in your `stream` processing pipeline. The type resolution algorithm is not that smarter as you think. However it will infer if you pass the values to the factory method. For an instance this will work.

```
Stream.of("ab", "abc").collect(Collectors.summingInt(CharSequence::length));
```

Comment: Thank you by the way for your answer, the problem is that I know how to fix the problem this way by explicitly setting the type parameter early in the `Stream.empty()` method. The problem is why java did not auto infer this from the context, i mean, i did collect the stream by a `Collector<CharSequence, ?, Integer>`, this must give a clue to java about the type of the input elements which is `CharSequence` no ?