# Why is this type inference not working with this Lambda expression scenario?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, type-inference

I have a weird scenario where type inference isn't working as I'd expect when using a lambda expression. Here's an approximation of my real scenario:

```
static class Value<T> {
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Bar<T> {
  T apply(Value<T> value); // Change here resolves error
}

static class Foo {
  public static <T> T foo(Bar<T> callback) {
  }
}

void test() {
  Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
}
```

The compile error I get on the second to last line is

> The method booleanValue() is undefined for the type Object

if I cast the lambda to `Bar<Boolean>`:

```
Foo.foo((Bar<Boolean>)value -> true).booleanValue();
```

or if I change the method signature of `Bar.apply` to use raw types:

```
T apply(Value value);
```

then the problem goes away. The way I'd expect this to work is that:

- `Foo.foo` call should infer a return type of `boolean`
- `value` in the lambda should be inferred to `Value<Boolean>`.

Why doesn't this inference work as expected and how can I change this API to make it work as expected?

Comment: Which Java Version you use?

Comment: @NwDx  Java 1.8.0_25

Comment: You simply have a type mismatch, because Boolean is not a Value<Boolean>. How the compiler should be able to know that T should be a Value<T>? And of course it don't know how, it assumes Object. Look at the [Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) Interface apply method. Value is a concrete type in context of your Bar Interface.

Comment: @NwDx I think what you're describing is the basis for @fukanchik's answer below. The problem there is that the compiler infers `Value<Object>` instead of `Value<Boolean>` which is what I'm after. Please feel free to share any ideas on how to get it to work.

Comment: I've made an update to my answer, may you have a look.

Comment: What if you use `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `true`?

Comment: If you were not throwing away the return type of Foo.foo, the compiler could use the target type to derive bounds for T...

Comment: @BrianGoetz Even without the target type, one can visually infer what the return type and lambda parameter type should be - what I expected them to be, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, type inference is not mind reading; it is constraint solving.  So the question is, where does the compiler get its constraints from.  The lambda body is not used to generate constraints (for good reasons.)  So while it's "obvious" to you that you meant that T=boolean, that the lambda returns boolean is not used as an input into type inference. So no, the compiler does not have the information needed to infer T in this case, with the return type ignored.

Comment: @BrianGoetz If the compiler doesn't use the lambda body to generate constraints, then why does changing `Bar` to use a raw `Value` type change anything?

Comment: @Jeffrey Raw types are viral. So changing the signature of apply() to use a raw type causes inference to treat the lambda as raw -- and now, from the perspective of inference, T doesn't appear *anywhere*, so there's nothing to infer.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I'm not sure if I understand your explanation. If there's nothing to infer, how does the compiler magically come up with `Boolean` as the type for `T` when it instantiates the method signature? Does it look at the lambda body in this case or is something else happening?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Under the Hood

Using some hidden `javac` features, we can get more information about what's happening:

```
$ javac -XDverboseResolution=deferred-inference,success,applicable LambdaInference.java 
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method foo in type Foo to candidate 0
    Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
       ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: <none>
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: <T>foo(Bar<T>)
        (partially instantiated to: (Bar<Object>)Object)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
    Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
           ^
  instantiated signature: (Bar<Object>)Object
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
                          ^
  symbol:   method booleanValue()
  location: class Object
1 error
```

This is a lot of information, let's break it down.

```
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method foo in type Foo to candidate 0
    Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
       ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: <none>
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: <T>foo(Bar<T>)
        (partially instantiated to: (Bar<Object>)Object)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
```

phase: [method applicability phase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2)
actuals: the actual arguments passed in
type-args: explicit type arguments
candidates: [potentially applicable methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1)

actuals is `<none>` because our implicitly typed lambda is not [pertinent to applicability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2).

The compiler resolves your invocation of `foo` to the only method named `foo` in `Foo`. It has been partially instantiated to `Foo.<Object> foo` (since there were no actuals or type-args), but that can change at the deferred-inference stage.

```
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
    Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
           ^
  instantiated signature: (Bar<Object>)Object
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
```

instantiated signature: the fully instantiated signature of `foo`. It is the result of this step (at this point no more type inference will be made on the signature of `foo`).
target-type: the context the call is being made in. If the method invocation is a part of an assignment, it will be the left hand side. If the method invocation is itself part of a method invocation, it will be the parameter type.

Since your method invocation is dangling, there is no target-type. Since there is no target-type, no more inference can be done on `foo` and `T` is inferred to be `Object`.

---

### Analysis

The compiler does not use implicitly typed lambdas during inference. To a certain extent, this makes sense. In general, given `param -> BODY`, you will not be able to compile `BODY` until you have a type for `param`. If you did try to infer the type for `param` from `BODY`, it might lead to a chicken-and-egg type problem. It's possible that some improvements will be made on this in future releases of Java.

---

### Solutions

`Foo.<Boolean> foo(value -> true)`

This solution provides an explicit type argument to `foo` (note the `with type-args` section below). This changes the partial instantiation of the method signature to `(Bar<Boolean>)Boolean`, which is what you want.

```
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method foo in type Foo to candidate 0
    Foo.<Boolean> foo(value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
       ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: <none>
  with type-args: Boolean
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: <T>foo(Bar<T>)
        (partially instantiated to: (Bar<Boolean>)Boolean)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method booleanValue in type Boolean to candidate 0
    Foo.<Boolean> foo(value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
                                    ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: no arguments
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: booleanValue()
```

---

`Foo.foo((Value<Boolean> value) -> true)`

This solution explicitly types your lambda, which allows it to be pertinent to applicability (note `with actuals` below). This changes the partial instantiation of the method signature to `(Bar<Boolean>)Boolean`, which is what you want.

```
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method foo in type Foo to candidate 0
    Foo.foo((Value<Boolean> value) -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
       ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: Bar<Boolean>
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: <T>foo(Bar<T>)
        (partially instantiated to: (Bar<Boolean>)Boolean)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
    Foo.foo((Value<Boolean> value) -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
           ^
  instantiated signature: (Bar<Boolean>)Boolean
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method booleanValue in type Boolean to candidate 0
    Foo.foo((Value<Boolean> value) -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
                                           ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: no arguments
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: booleanValue()
```

---

`Foo.foo((Bar<Boolean>) value -> true)`

Same as above, but with a slightly different flavor.

```
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method foo in type Foo to candidate 0
    Foo.foo((Bar<Boolean>) value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
       ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: Bar<Boolean>
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: <T>foo(Bar<T>)
        (partially instantiated to: (Bar<Boolean>)Boolean)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
    Foo.foo((Bar<Boolean>) value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
           ^
  instantiated signature: (Bar<Boolean>)Boolean
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method booleanValue in type Boolean to candidate 0
    Foo.foo((Bar<Boolean>) value -> true).booleanValue(); // Compile error here
                                         ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: no arguments
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: booleanValue()
```

---

`Boolean b = Foo.foo(value -> true)`

This solution provides an explicit target for your method call (see `target-type` below). This allows the deferred-instantiation to infer that the type parameter should be `Boolean` instead of `Object` (see `instantiated signature` below).

```
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method foo in type Foo to candidate 0
    Boolean b = Foo.foo(value -> true);
                   ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: <none>
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: <T>foo(Bar<T>)
        (partially instantiated to: (Bar<Object>)Object)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
    Boolean b = Foo.foo(value -> true);
                       ^
  instantiated signature: (Bar<Boolean>)Boolean
  target-type: Boolean
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
```

---

### Disclaimer

This is the behavior that's occurring. I don't know if this is what is specified in the JLS. I could dig around and see if I could find the exact section that specifies this behavior, but [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) notation gives me a headache.

This also doesn't fully explain why changing `Bar` to use a raw `Value` would fix this issue:

```
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method foo in type Foo to candidate 0
    Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue();
       ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: <none>
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: <T>foo(Bar<T>)
        (partially instantiated to: (Bar<Object>)Object)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
    Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue();
           ^
  instantiated signature: (Bar<Boolean>)Boolean
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>foo(Bar<T>)
LambdaInference.java:16: Note: resolving method booleanValue in type Boolean to candidate 0
    Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue();
                          ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: no arguments
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: booleanValue()
```

For some reason, changing it to use a raw `Value` allows the deferred instantiation to infer that `T` is `Boolean`. If I had to speculate, I would guess that when the compiler tries to fit the lambda to the `Bar<T>`, it can infer that `T` is `Boolean` by looking at the body of the lambda. This implies that my earlier analysis is incorrect. The compiler *can* perform type inference on the body of a lambda, but only on type variables that *only* appear in the return type.

Answer (score 6):

Inference on lambda parameter type cannot depend on the lambda body.

The compiler faces a tough job trying to make sense of implicit lambda expressions

```
    foo( value -> GIBBERISH )
```

The type of `value` must be inferred first before GIBBERISH can be compiled, because in general the interpretation of GIBBERISH depends on the definition of `value`.

*(In your special case, GIBBERISH happens to be a simple constant independent of `value`.)*

Javac must infer `Value<T>` first for parameter `value`; there's no constraints in context, therefore `T=Object`. Then, lambda body `true` is compiled and recognized as Boolean, compatible with `T`.

After you made the change to the functional interface, the lambda parameter type does not require inference; T remains uninfered. Next, the lambda body is compiled, and the return type appears to be Boolean, which is set as a lower bound for `T`.

---

Another example demonstrating the issue

```
<T> void foo(T v, Function<T,T> f) { ... }

foo("", v->42);  // Error. why can't javac infer T=Object ?
```

T is inferred to be `String`; the body of lambda did not participate in the inference.

In this example, javac's behavior seems very reasonable to us; it likely prevented a programming error.
You don't want inference to be too powerful; if everything we write compiles somehow, we'll lose the confidence on compiler finding errors for us.

---

There are other examples where lambda body appears to provide unequivocal constraints, yet the compiler cannot use that information. In Java, the lambda parameter types must be fixed first, before the body can be looked at. This is a deliberate decision. In contrast, C# is willing to try different parameter types and see which makes the code compile. Java considers that too risky.

In any case, when implicit lambda fails, which happens rather frequently, provide explicit types for lambda parameters; in your case, `(Value<Boolean> value)->true`

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to fix this is a type declaration on the method call to `foo`:

```
Foo.<Boolean>foo(value -> true).booleanValue();
```

*Edit:* I can't find the specific documentation about why this is necessary, pretty much just like everyone else. I suspected it might be because of primitive types, but that wasn't right. Regardless, This syntax is called using a [Target Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). Also [Target Type in Lambdas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing). The reasons elude me though, I can't find documentation anywhere on why this particular use case is necessary.

*Edit 2:* I found this relevant question:

[Generic type inference not working with method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794924/generic-type-inference-not-working-with-method-chaining)

It looks like it's because you're chaining the methods here. According to the JSR comments referenced in the accepted answer there, it was a deliberate omission of functionality because the compiler doesn't have a way to pass inferred generic type information between chained method calls in both directions. As a result, the entire type of erased by time it gets to the call to `booleanValue`. Adding the target type in removes this behavior by providing the constraint manually instead of letting the compiler make the decision using the rules outlined in [JLS §18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html), which doesn't seem to mention this at all. This is the only info I could come up with. If anyone finds anything better, I'd love to see it.

Comment: I'm not sure if a JLS reference is necessary - I'm just curious in general why inference doesn't seem to work here and if there's any change I can make to the API to make it work. Ideally, I don't want to require my users to have to manually supply the type argument here.

Comment: It's all about the way they do type inference with their algorithm and primitives. Have you tried returning Boolean.TRUE instead of just true? I'm not in front of an IDE, I can't test at the moment.

Comment: Returning an object like String or Boolean.TRUE yields the same sort of problem.

Comment: Sorry to mislead you, take a look at my edits, hopefully it's the right info. This stuff is hard to research.

Comment: If it was a problem with chaining methods, I wouldn't expect a change of signature to `T apply(Value value);` to have any positive effect, yet it does.

Comment: @Brian That syntax is not called target typing. Target typing would be `Boolean b = Foo.foo(value -> true);` The syntax you describe (`Foo.<Boolean> foo(value->true)`) is known as a *type witness*.

Answer (score 3):

Like other answers, I am also hoping someone smarter can point out ***why*** the compiler isn't able to infer that `T` is `Boolean`.

One way to help out the compiler do the right thing, without requiring any changes to your existing class/interface design, is by explicitly declaring the formal parameter's type in your lambda expression.  So, in this case, by explicitly declaring that the type of the `value` parameter is `Value<Boolean>`.

```
void test() {
  Foo.foo((Value<Boolean> value) -> true).booleanValue();
}
```

Comment: I can change the class/interface design a bit so long as the `Foo.foo` call infers a return type of boolean and `value` in the lambda is inferred to `Value<Boolean>`. I don't want to cast since this is part of a public API and requiring a cast creates a usability problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, my example does not perform any casting.  It merely is explicit about the formal parameter type of the lambda expression rather than inferring the type.  But yes, I would also like to know why you can't simply infer the correct type in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but you need to add separate return type:

```
public class HelloWorld{
static class Value<T> {
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Bar<T,R> {
      R apply(Value<T> value); // Return type added
}

static class Foo {
  public static <T,R> R foo(Bar<T,R> callback) {
      return callback.apply(new Value<T>());
  }
}

void test() {
  System.out.println( Foo.foo(value -> true).booleanValue() ); // No compile error here
}
     public static void main(String []args){
         new HelloWorld().test();
     }
}
```

some smart guy probably can explain that.

Comment: That gets us a bit closer, but `value` in the lambda expression is inferred to `Value<Object>` instead of `Value<Boolean>` which will still cause problems in my real scenario where the lambda expression body contains more code...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My guess is: you need type wildcard if you want to call methods on T `static class Value<T extends Boolean>, interface Bar<T extends Boolean,R>, public static <T extends Boolean,R> R foo(Bar<T,R> callback)`, etc...

Comment: Something like that seems like it could work, except the return type from the lambda could be anything (controlled by users). Boolean is just an example...

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Value will infer to type `Value<Object>` because you interpreted the lambda wrong. Think of it, like you call with the lambda directly the apply method. So what you do is:

```
Boolean apply(Value value);
```

and this is correctly inferred to:

```
Boolean apply(Value<Object> value);
```

since you haven't given the type for Value.

### Simple Solution

Call the lambda in a correct way:

```
Foo.foo((Value<Boolean> value) -> true).booleanValue();
```

this will be inferred to:

```
Boolean apply(Value<Boolean> value);
```

### (My) Recommended Solution

Your solution should be a bit more clear. If you want a callback, then you need a type value which will be returned.

I've made a generic Callback interface, a generic Value class and an UsingClass to show how to use it.

#### Callback interface

```
/**
 *
 * @param <P> The parameter to call
 * @param <R> The return value you get
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Callback<P, R> {

  public R call(P param);
}
```

#### Value class

```
public class Value<T> {

  private final T field;

  public Value(T field) {
    this.field = field;
  }

  public T getField() {
    return field;
  }
}
```

#### UsingClass class

```
public class UsingClass<T> {

  public T foo(Callback<Value<T>, T> callback, Value<T> value) {
    return callback.call(value);
  }
}
```

#### TestApp with main

```
public class TestApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Value<Boolean> boolVal = new Value<>(false);
    Value<String> stringVal = new Value<>("false");

    Callback<Value<Boolean>, Boolean> boolCb = (v) -> v.getField();
    Callback<Value<String>, String> stringCb = (v) -> v.getField();

    UsingClass<Boolean> usingClass = new UsingClass<>();
    boolean val = usingClass.foo(boolCb, boolVal);
    System.out.println("Boolean value: " + val);

    UsingClass<String> usingClass1 = new UsingClass<>();
    String val1 = usingClass1.foo(stringCb, stringVal);
    System.out.println("String value: " + val1);

    // this will give you a clear and understandable compiler error
    //boolean val = usingClass.foo(boolCb, stringVal);
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to get away from the example scenario a bit, which is a simplification of a real API. Two things: the foo method needs to be static and should take a single argument.

Comment: @JoshStone Which API you are talking about. What I've done is in JavaFX a bit like the Callback for a Table Cell Value Factory. That you want it static is not the problem I guess. But only one value? Sorry, but then you probably need a [predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) and not a function or callback.

Comment: It's worth mentioning again - this will be part of a public API, so it needs to be simple to use. The user needs to be able to provide a basic lambda like `value -> true` for which value will be inferred to `Value<Boolean>` and the method accepting the lambda will return `Boolean`. Any other changes are fine but those need to stay in place to make the API usable.

Comment: Hm, to me an API should be flexible and abstract. What you've done in Bar is working with a concrete Type, this isn't flexible at all.

Comment: It's just an example to illustrate the problem. The goal with the real API isn't flexibility, it's simplicity, which is why we want `foo` to accept a single argument in order to make this work.