# Java fails to properly infer stream type without apparently redundant typecast

Tags: java, arrays, casting, java-stream, inference

I'm doing a series of streaming operations to flatten what's effectively a 2D array.

```
Arrays.stream(attributes)
    .map(Attribute::getCommand)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .flatMap((array) -> (Arrays.stream((String[]) array)))
    .toArray(String[]::new)
```

Where `Attribute` conforms to the following interface:

```
public interface Attribute<T> {
  Optional<String[]> getCommand();  
}
```

However, the final `flatMap()` call isn't operating as expected.

- `.flatMap((array) -> (Arrays.stream((String[]) array)))` works just fine.
- `.flatMap((array) -> (Arrays.stream(array)))` **fails to compile** with `java: no suitable method found for stream(java.lang.Object)`.
- `.flatMap(Arrays::stream)` **fails to compile** with `java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T[])`.

It seems to me that the type should be inferred just fine though. IntelliJ agrees and marks the cast as redundant and shows no compile errors with any of the three implementations. **Why does Java require this apparently redundant typecast?**

---

I additionally tried the following minimalist implementation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Streaming {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional<String[]>[] myarray = new Optional[]{Optional.of(new String[]{"Hello", "world"}),
        Optional.empty(), Optional.of(new String[]{"Foo"})};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(myarray).filter(Optional::isPresent).map
        (Optional::get).flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(String[]::new)));
  }

}
```

And it works just fine with all three implementations, outputting the expected `[Hello, world, Foo]`.

---

**Edit:**

This was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227149/why-is-this-type-inference-not-working-with-this-lambda-expression-scenario). I may be wrong, but it seems that there's a distinction since this the type is specified in a more explicit manner. Notably, IntelliJ agrees that the cast is necessary in the example provided on said post, but not for my code. If I am mistaken, please let me know.

---

**Edit:**

Per request, the declaration of `attributes` is `Attribute[] attributes = new Attribute[]{...}` where `...` is a variety of implementations of Attribute.

Comment: Java only infers one level of method calls. It doesn't infer the type of nested lambda expressions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Okay, I think I get it. So Java is able to infer the return type of `Arrays.stream(attributes).map(Attribute::getCommand).filter(Optional::isPresent)` as `Optional` since it has an explicit return type, but not further, yes?

Comment: yes, I am not sure why there is this limitation but I guess it is the simplify type interference.

Comment: @JMY1000 It can be a bit confusing for relatively new users, but duplicate does not necessarily mean duplicate *question*, but duplicate *answer*. I would trust the person that closed the question that you can find your answer in the 10+ highly detailed answers on both posts.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I'm aware of that, I'm fairly acquainted with SE. As you can see in the answer below and other comments, the pertinent bit isn't the same in the answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: Then maybe @JohnKugelman can reopen the question? I'm really not a subject matter expert, but that would be valid ground to reopen.

Comment: @FélixGagnon the -Grenier Potentially, it's also possible that I've misinterpreted it (in which case it'd be nice to get an explanation as to what I've misinterpreted.) The raw type question is closer, but I'm still not entirely sure how I should handle things for my particular use case.

Answer (score 2):

`Attribute` is a generic class (I wonder why as `T` is not used).
If you have this error it means that you declared a raw type of that such as :

```
Attribute[] attributes = ...;
```

For a raw type, the return type of `getCommand()` that is declared as `Optional<String[]>` becomes just `Optional`.
Declare `Attribute` as a generic type, for example : `Attribute<String>[] attributes = ...;` and this should compile without the cast or just remove the parameterized type `T` if it is not required.

Comment: @JMY1000 What is your `attributes` declaration?

Comment: Attribute is a generic class : `class Attribute<T>` : look a the `<T>`. And you seem to declare a raw type : `Attribute` and not a generic type : `Attribute<SomeType>`.

Comment: But `getCommand()` is declared with return type `Optional<String[]>`, not `Optional<T[]>` or something. Why does the type suddenly get ignored?

Comment: read again my answer : `For a raw type, the return type of getCommand() that is declared as Optional<String[]> becomes just Optional.`

Comment: @davidxxx Gotcha, thanks. I think I'm probably just missing something from the duplicate question, but why does this occur?

Comment: Your question has probably a duplicate but a thing is sure : not the referenced duplicate. Why does this occur? Because it is the way which the raw types work and whatever you use lambdas or not.

Comment: I think that your question is a little misleading because  we don't see the declared type for the array of Attributes that you stream. I think that you can delete it as it will probably not help others.