# Java Generics, Type Erasure, wildcard and Function<?...> produce incompatible types

Tags: java, generics, java-8, wildcard

One more rookie question, sorry about that.

Let's consider the following code:

```
public class ExceptionHandler {

   // simple internal manager
   @FunctionalInterface
   private interface ExceptionManager<D extends Exception> {
     int getErrorCode(D e, WebRequest request, 
                      HttpServletRequest servletRequest);
   }

   // One field, just for the illustration 
   // (TypeMismatchException came from spring framework)
   private ExceptionManager<TypeMismatchException> tmeManager = 
      (ex, req, servletRequest) -> {
         int errorCode = 0;
         // ...
         return errorCode;
      };

   // A simple "factory" for an ExceptionManager
   private Function<? extends Exception, 
          Optional<ExceptionManager<? extends Exception>>> factory = (ex) -> {
      if(ex instanceof TypeMismatchException) {
         return Optional.of(tmeManager);
      }
      /* ... */
      return Optional.empty();
   };

   // global  exception manager
   private ExceptionManager<? extends Exception> defaultExceptionManager =
      (exception, request, servletRequest) -> {

         final Optional<ExceptionManager<? extends Exception>> manager = 
                         factory.apply(exception);

         if(manager.isPresent()) {
            return manager.get()
                    .getErrorCode(exception, request, servletRequest);
         }
         return 1;
      };
}
```

The following code cannot compile. It's actually complaints about a type incompatibility problem.

```
Error:(...) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Exception
      cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Exception
Error:(...) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Exception
      cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.Exception
```

After thinking and reading about the problem, it seems that java perform a type erasure (for jvm backward compatibility) and thus the code:

```
private ExceptionManager<? extends Exception> defaultExceptionManager = 
                   (exception, request, servletRequest) -> { /* ... */ }
```

became

```
private ExceptionManager<Exception> defaultExceptionManager = 
                   (exception, request, servletRequest) -> { /* ... */ }
```

Which is actually fix the first parameter of the `getErrorCode` (namely `exception`) to `Exception`.

As I understand (not sure about really understand actually), the process should  be the same for the generic type. Thus

```
private interface ExceptionManager<D extends Exception> { /* ... */ }
```

should became

```
private interface ExceptionManager<Exception> { /* ... */ }
```

and consequently also fix the parameter `e` in the `getErrorCode` method to `Exception`.
The type incompatibility probleme became a bit more clear after (if I'm right). However, I'm still doubtfully about the `capture#xx of ? extends Exception` since this means (still according to my comprehension) that the Type Erasure is not effective for the whole part of code.

***Can someone point me out of the error in the code (and may be a documentation which I can find some explanation about the internal behavior of the compiler for generics, wildcard and type erasure) ?***

**Note**: the code also complains about an incompatible type.

```
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleTypeMismatch(final TypeMismatchException ex,
   final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status,
   final WebRequest request) {
   /* ... */
   int errorCode = defaultExceptionManager.getErrorCode(ex, request, servletRequest);
}
```

The result of this call is

```
Error:(154, 63) java: incompatible types:
      org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException
      cannot be converted to capture#3 of ? extends java.lang.Exception
```

Sorry for the length of this question and thanks for reading and answering to it!
Regards

Comment: I think the first answer here describes how to find out what's going wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227149/why-is-this-type-inference-not-working-with-this-lambda-expression-scenario

Comment: What happens if you cast the lambda explicitly before assigning? `ExceptionManager<? extends Exception> defaultExceptionManager =
      (ExceptionManager<? extends Exception>) ((exception, request, servletRequest) -> { ... )` ? And, btw, wouldn't a simple `ExceptionManager<Exception>` do the job?

Comment: Thanks for both responses @JohnB (the post you point out is pretty interesting and didn't land on it before). For the second point, the cast doesn't change the behavior. For the second point, I wanna be able to keep genericity in the interface so that I can write manager (ex: `ExceptionManager<TypeMismatchException> tmeManager`) without casting anything inside the implementation. Note that the structure of the code is mainly for learning how to deal with some features of java8 (function, lambda and generics). One more thanks for your time and your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a function like `Function<? extends Exception, …>`, you’re saying that the type of the parameter is unknown and consequently, you can not `apply` this function as you don’t know whether the actual argument is compatible to the unknown parameter type. The same applies to the `ExceptionManager<? extends Exception>`, which receives an unknown exception type as argument.

This is different from not knowing the return type, as when a function returns `? extends R`, you still know that the result is assignable to `R` or a super type of `R`.

There is a relationship between the incoming argument and the result type which would make this code usable if it was generic, however, you can’t make a variable (holding a reference to a `Function`) generic. You can solve this with using ordinary methods, which can declare type parameters. This is almost straight-forward, as you’re overusing functions here anyway:

```
public class ExceptionHandler {
    // simple internal manager
    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface ExceptionManager<D extends Exception> {
        int getErrorCode(D e, WebRequest request, HttpServletRequest servletRequest);
    }
    // One field, just for the illustration 
    private static ExceptionManager<TypeMismatchException> tmeManager = 
       (ex, req, servletRequest) -> {
          int errorCode = 0;
          // ...
          return errorCode;
       };

    // A simple "factory" for an ExceptionManager
    private static <E extends Exception> Optional<ExceptionManager<E>> factory(E ex) {
        if(ex instanceof TypeMismatchException) {
            // unavoidable unchecked operation
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") ExceptionManager<E> em
                                         = (ExceptionManager<E>)tmeManager;
            return Optional.of(em);
        }
        /* ... */
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    // global  exception manager
    private ExceptionManager<Exception> defaultExceptionManager
                                      = ExceptionHandler::handleDefault;

    static <E extends Exception> int handleDefault(E exception, WebRequest request, 
                                                   HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        final Optional<ExceptionManager<E>> manager = factory(exception);
        return manager.map(em -> em.getErrorCode(exception, request, servletRequest))
                      .orElse(1);
    }
}
```

There’s one place where an unchecked operation is unavoidable, when returning a specific handler found to be suitable through an `instanceof` check. Care must be taken here, as the exception could be a sub-type `TypeMismatchException`. It’s also possible that the instance is a `TypeMismatchException` at runtime, but the caller has substituted a super type of it for `E`. The latter is the more dangerous scenario, as the generic signature would promise to be able to process broader types than it actually can. As long as the method is `private`, you can easily overview that the caller(s) only pass the same instance as used for the check, so it’ll work.