# Can't understand Flink's TypeInformation when using returns

Tags: apache-flink

I have following simple code to demonstrate the usage of TypeInformation.

I don't understand why I need to place `(FlatMapFunction<List<String>, String>)` in  the code,
what does it do?If I remove it, then the compiler complains that `Cannot resolve method returns(TypeInformation<T>)'`

Thanks!

```
    @Test
    public void testTypeInformation() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        DataStreamSource<List<String>> phoneTypeDS = env.addSource(new SourceFunction<List<String>>() {
            private Boolean isCancel = false;

            public void run(SourceFunction.SourceContext<List<String>> sourceContext) throws Exception {
                while (!isCancel) {
                    List<String> phoneTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    phoneTypeList.add("iphone");
                    phoneTypeList.add("xiaomi");
                    phoneTypeList.add("meizu");

                    sourceContext.collect(phoneTypeList);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                }
            }

            public void cancel() {
                isCancel = true;
            }
        });

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> eachTypeDS = phoneTypeDS.flatMap(
                //here is the question code.
                (FlatMapFunction<List<String>, String>) (value, out) -> value.stream().forEach(v -> out.collect(v)))
                .returns(TypeInformation.of(String.class));

        eachTypeDS.print();
        env.execute("GenericTypeTest");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With generics (like `List<String>`) you get type erasure, where the type information is removed during the Java compilation step. So at runtime it's not possible to know the type inside of the `List`. Flink then requires some help from you to tell it (at runtime, when the workflow graph is being generated) what type is actually being used. See [this Flink doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/types_serialization/#type-erasure--type-inference) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @kkrugler. I know what you are saying about `runtime type erasure`, My confusion is about `(FlatMapFunction<List<String>, String>)`, what does it do?To overcome the limitation of java type inference?, that I need to tell flink or compiler explicitly?

Comment: Type inference with lambda expressions is a very complex topic, and not specific to Flink. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227149/why-is-this-type-inference-not-working-with-this-lambda-expression-scenario for one SO discussion on this topic. My rule of thumb w/Flink is if I have generic types, I avoid using lambdas and just create a simple private static class.