# Java8 - nested stream and unchecked exception

Tags: exception, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to throw an unechecked runtime exception in a nested stream. For some reason, this seems not possible. Why?

See example below. Please note that the logic does not make much sense. It is just for demonstration purposes.

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    list.stream()
            .map(item -> list.stream()
                    .filter(item2 -> item.equals(item2))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the compiler can't infer the type of the exception.

Just use

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    list.stream()
        .map(item -> list.stream()
                         .filter(item2 -> item.equals(item2))
                         .findFirst()
                         .<RuntimeException>orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to report to javac buglist.

Comment: @DaveTeezo I don't think it's a bug - type inference does not work well with method chaining, but that is due to the specification rather than the implementation. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794924/generic-type-inference-not-working-with-method-chaining