# Convert Consumer into Runnable inside Stream.map()

Tags: java, eclipse, java-stream, functional-interface

I am trying to convert a `Consumer` to a `Runnable`.  The following code does **not** generate any compiler errors in Eclipse IDE.

```
Consumer<Object> consumer;
Runnable runnable;
Object value;

...
runnable = () -> consumer.accept(value);
```

The following code generates a compiler error in Eclipse IDE.

```
ArrayList<Consumer<Object>> list;
Object value;

...

list.
   stream().
   map(consumer -> () -> consumer.accept(value));
```

The errors are:

```
Type mismatch: Can not convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>.
The target type of this expression must be a functional interface.
```

How do I help the compiler convert a `Consumer` to a `Runnable`?

The following code fixes the problem but is very verbose.

```
map(consumer -> (Runnable) (() -> consumer.accept(value)));
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?  I know I could create a static method which accepts a `Consumer` and returns a `Runnable`, but I don't think of that as more concise.

Comment: At least, you can omit one pair of round braces: `.map(consumer -> (Runnable) ()->consumer.accept(value))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message is normal if you consider the expression:

```
list.stream().map(consumer -> () -> consumer.accept(value))
                              ^--------------------------^
                                what is the type of that?
```

The problem is that the compiler has no way of determining the target type of the expression `() -> consumer.accept(value)`. It certainly can be `Runnable`, but it could also be `MyAwesomeInterface` declared with:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyAwesomeInterface { void foo(); }
```

In fact, it can comply to any functional interface that declares a functional method taking no parameter and returning no value. As such, this results in a compilation error.

There is no error when you explicitly store the lambda expression in a `Runnable` with:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> consumer.accept(value);
```

because, then the compiler knows that the target type of that lambda is `Runnable`.

---

The problem is more obscure when you consider:

```
List<Runnable> runnables = list.stream()
                               .map(consumer -> () -> consumer.accept(value))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

One could argue that the compiler may be able to infer the target type of that expression to be `Runnable` since we're collecting that into a list of `Runnable`. But, [it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24794924/1743880) and you have to help the compiler out a little and explicitly tell the compiler that the `Stream` elements are `Runnable`:

```
List<Runnable> runnables = list.stream()
                               .<Runnable> map(consumer -> () -> consumer.accept(value))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So in the end, `<Runnable>map(...)` is more concise.

Comment: @Nathan That's more a matter of preference. IMO, it's prettier than the cast (but that's just my opinion).

Comment: It was much easier, if `Consumer` had a `bind` method…