# Filter out values when converting List<SomeObject> to Map<String, Set<String>> using Java 8 streams API

Tags: java

This problem is related to [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587730/converting-listmyobject-to-mapstring-liststring-in-java-8-when-we-have-du)

I have an instances of Student class.

```
class Student {
    String name;
    String addr;
    String type;

    public Student(String name, String addr, String type) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.addr = addr;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", addr=" + addr + "]";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddr() {
        return addr;
    }
}
```

And I have a code to create a map , where it store the student name as the **key** and some processed addr values (a List since we have multiple **addr** values for the same student) as the value.

```
public class FilterId {

    public static String getNum(String s) {
        // should do some complex stuff, just for testing
        return s.split(" ")[1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student("a", "test 1", "type 1"));
        list.add(new Student("a", "test 1", "type 2"));
        list.add(new Student("b", "test 1", "type 1"));
        list.add(new Student("c", "test 1", "type 1"));
        list.add(new Student("b", "test 1", "type 1"));
        list.add(new Student("a", "test 1", "type 1"));
        list.add(new Student("c", "test 3", "type 2"));
        list.add(new Student("a", "test 2", "type 1"));
        list.add(new Student("b", "test 2", "type 1"));
        list.add(new Student("a", "test 3", "type 3"));
        list.add(new Student("a", "my test 4", "type 1"));
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

I can have a code like below to get an out put like this. `{a=[1, 2, 3], b=[1, 2], c=[1, 3]}`

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = list.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Student::getName,
    Collectors.mapping(student -> getNum(student.getAddr()),
        Collectors.toSet())));
```

But how can we add an extra checks to this,

like, `if the type is  type 3, then that entry should not go to the Set for that student` ,

And add another constraint check to `getNum` like,

```
    public static String getNum(String s) {
        // should do some complex stuff, just for testing
        if(s.contains("my")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return s.split(" ")[1];
        }
    }
```

And I don't need to add that empty string to the `set` associated with that Student.

So the expected output for that case will be,  `{a=[1, 2], b=[1, 2], c=[1, 3]}` Since `a`'s `test 3` is `type 3` one. And the `a`'s `my test 4` is also not considered since it fails the check as well.

How can I achive this target with Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert the `filter()` call before starting the grouping (with the `Predicate` of your choice):

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = list.stream()
  .filter(s -> !s.type.equals("type 3"))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Student::getName,
    Collectors.mapping(student -> getNum(student.getAddr()), Collectors.toSet())));
```

Result:
`{a=[1, 2, test], b=[1, 2], c=[1, 3]}`

Comment: What about the other condition, So that the output will be `{a=[1, 2], b=[1, 2], c=[1, 3]}` (without the `test` element for `a`)

Comment: @prime you expand the Predicate in the filter call - I thought that the question was more about where to put the filter call and not how to write the predicate

Answer (score 1):

This should be good for all of requirements and no need to have `getNum` method:

```
Map< String, Set<String> > map = list.stream()
.filter( s -> !Objects.equals( s.getType(), "type 3") )
.filter( s -> !s.getAddr().contains("my") )
.collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Student::getName, 
          Collectors.mapping( s -> s.getAddr().split(" ")[1], Collectors.toSet() ) ) );
```