# What is the type of Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed()?

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have a list of map entries

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
...(fill the map)...
List<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
```

and I want to sort it by values according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2581754/9772691), but in reverse order. When I do

```
Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> cmp = Entry.comparingByValue();
entries.sort(cmp.reversed());
```

everything works fine. But when I try to shorten the above two lines to

```
entries.sort(Entry.comparingByValue().reversed());
```

the compiler returns

```
error: incompatible types: Comparator<Entry<Object,V>> cannot be converted to Comparator<? super Entry<String,Integer>>
        entries.sort(Entry.comparingByValue().reversed());
  where V is a type-variable:
    V extends Comparable<? super V>
```

This seems strange because the implementation of Comparator's `reversed()` default method simply transfers it to `Collections.reverseOrder()` and I can change the above line to

```
entries.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(Entry.comparingByValue()));
```

to work. But what is the correct type of `Entry.comparingByValue().reversed()`?

```
Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> cmp = Entry.comparingByValue().reversed();
```

doesn't seem to work. Omitting the type parameter `Entry<String, Integer>` works, but this results in "unchecked method invocation" warning from the compiler later.

Comment: Check answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794924/generic-type-inference-not-working-with-method-chaining

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The compiler is not clever enough to infer the generic type parameters in this case. You can specify them explicitly:

```
entries.sort(Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed());
```

The issue is that you first need the type of the comparator returned by `comparingByValue` to know the type of the one returned by `reversed`.

I don't see any good reason why a clever compiler couldn't work backwards and know that `sort` requires a particular type, so `reversed` must be a particular type, so `comparingByValue` must be a particular type. But that's not how things are.

Type inference is still being worked on ([as recently as Java 10](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)), so maybe in the future, who knows.

Answer (score 7):

When you shorten down

```
Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> cmp = Entry.comparingByValue();
entries.sort(cmp.reversed());
```

to

```
entries.sort(Entry.comparingByValue().reversed());
```

you remove the type information gleaned from `cmp`’s declaration. The compiler still needs to know that information, so you need to add the generic typing to `Entry`:

```
entries.sort(Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed());
```

Comment: Oops, looks like I put the `.` in the wrong place. Fixed now.