# Sort on multiple properties on Integer List

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, comparator

I have a list of integers, and would like to print all their elements in a sorted way, by 2 properties: list size and the sum of the elements on the list. I read on streams `thenComparing` method, but an error shows up whenever I try to use it.

I wrote some code that is working, but would like to know if there is any other cleaner way to do it. Thanks in advance!

```java
Map<List<Integer>, Double> entropies = new HashMap<>();

// Extra code removed

entropies.keySet()
    .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> {
        List<Integer> a = (List<Integer>) o;
        return a.size();
    }).thenComparingInt(o -> {
        List<Integer> a = (List<Integer>) o;
        return a.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    }))
    .forEach(key -> logger.debug("{} => {}", key, entropies.get(key)));
```

Same as actual output but without castings would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
entropies.keySet()
         .stream().sorted(Comparator.<List<Integer>>comparingInt(List::size)
                              .thenComparingInt(o -> o.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()))
         .forEach(key -> logger.debug("{} => {}", key, entropies.get(key)));
```

Since `Comparator.comparingInt` is not able to infer the type as List>. The type hint when you call let's the compiler know the actual type. This is because the `sorted` method expects `Comparator<? super List<Integer>> comparator`, so technically your comparator could have any superclass of List, so you need to explicitly specify which superclass it is.

Comment: Nice summary for why having to add the type hint;  further details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794924/generic-type-inference-not-working-with-method-chaining .  Also a second option is to use `o -> o.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(i->i))`

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. But more than that, you provided a explanation on why what I tried to do didn't work and what I needed to change.
Also, thanks to racraman to provide more details on this and on that second option.

Comment: You can also use the slightly simpler `Comparator.comparingInt(List<Integer>::size)  .thenComparingInt(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())` Also, an explicitely typed lambda expression would work: `Comparator.comparingInt((List<Integer> l) -> l.size())  .thenComparingInt(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())`