# return list of hashmap keys after sorting?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda

i try to sort a hashmap and return a list of the result keys. This is what i have tried:

```
public List<City> getCities() {

Map<Node<City>, Edge> map = new HashMap<>();

// add entries to map ...

return map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<Node<City>, Edge>comparingByValue())
            .map(e -> e.getKey().getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

The edges implement compairable and the getValue() method will return a City object.

```
public class Edge<T> implements Comparable<Edge<T>> {

private Node<T> a;
private Node<T> b;

private double weight;

public Edge(Node<T> a, Node<T> b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public void setWeight(double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return sum;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Edge<T> o) {
    return Double.compare(getWeight(), o.getWeight());
}

}
```

Now my IDE doesn't complain about anything but when i compile i get this error:

> Error:(104, 28) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   method getKey()
>     location: variable e of type java.lang.Object

I know it is not nice to just post some code and an error. But actually i searched for an hour and found nothing. Also for me the code makes absolutely sence and i have no idea why getKey of the entry is not recognized.

So what is going on? why do i get this error?

Comment: At first glance, i cannot find anything that’s wrong. So for further debugging, i would recommend to replace the lambda expression with an anonymous Function<> class. Perhaps this will produce a more helpful error message, if any.

Comment: There is something wrong with the type of the stream elements. map is a HashMap<Node<City>, Edge>. map.entrySet() gives a Set<Map.Entry<Node<City>, Edge>>. map.entrySet().stream() gives a Stream<Map.Entry<Node<City>, Edge>> sorted() should not change the element type of the stream. And so e should be a Map.Entry<Node<City>, Edge>. But it is an Object, and Object does know nothing about getKey(). Perhaps your UI’s debugger can show you where the element type changes to Object.

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn - This is a compilation error.  The debugger won't help finding it.

Comment: @SvenSteve If you remove the .map() line AND if the program compiles, the Debugger might help. Be creative ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that your class `Edge` is implementing Comparable by:

```
class Edge implements Comparable
```

Change your class Edge declaration to:

```
class Edge implements Comparable<Edge>
```

Or split your return logic by:

```
Stream<Map.Entry<Node<City>, Edge>> sorted = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
return sorted
        .map(e -> e.getKey().getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Problem is due to type inference of generics on chained invocation. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794924/generic-type-inference-not-working-with-method-chaining) might give you more details.

Comment: Thank you! Edge<T> already implemeted Comparable<Edge<T>> so that didn't change it. However splitting it worked which makes sence because it is now casting to an entry and not Object. Anyways i still don't understand why it wasn't casting correctly. I added the Edge class to the question...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your classes but I believe this is what you want.

```java
      Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("Z", 10, "X", 8, "Y", 9);

      // add entries to map ...

      List<String> keys = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(
            Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue())).map(
                  e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());

      System.out.println(keys);
```

In your example, `.map(e -> e.getKey().getValue())` should be   `.map(e ->e.getKey())`