# Cannot return Stream of subclass objects after filtering

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, type-inference

I have a method that returns a `Stream` of type `A`. I also have a subtype `B` of `A`. The method creates a `Stream` that it populates with instances of `B`, which are also of type `A` due to inheritance. This works fine, until I introduce a filter on the `Stream`. Then, the compiler decides that the Stream is of type `B` and not `A`, and inheritance does not seem to matter. Why does this happen?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    abstract class A {
        int member;
    }

    class B extends A {

        public B(int member) {
            this.member = member;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<A> stream = getStream();
    }

    private Stream<A> getStream() {
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        ints.add(1);
        ints.add(2);
        ints.add(3);

        return ints.stream().map(B::new).filter(b -> true); // Filter causes compiler to throw error
    }

}
```

Comment: Just return `Stream<? extends A>` in method `getStream()`

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good solution. Would like to learn about exactly why I can't do what I'm doing though.

Comment: Because [generics in Java are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant)

Comment: But how come the filter breaks everything? It works fine until I use a filter. Does the filter cast the `Stream<A>` to `Stream<B>`?

Comment: Ah right, didn't see that. Well, then I only have an unsatisfactory answer: because Java's type inference coupled with generics is mad. Like, seriously mad. It probably has somethig to do with fact that `map` accepts a covariant param while `filter` takes variant one. Edit: not this rabbit-hole again... bookmarked, if I come up with something I'll come back here.

Comment: You could cast it to a `Stream<A>`, but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: Casting won't work, you'll get 'inconvertible types'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Holger, for setting the record straight. This is a case of type inference of generics types not having been expanded to [chained invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794924/generic-type-inference-not-working-with-method-chaining) because of the added complexity it would bring. So as soon as you chain the `filter()` call, the inference mechanism can't determine the type automatically anymore.

You don't need to cast with an additional clumsy `.map(A.class::cast)`, [modify the return type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) to `Stream<? extends A>` or do anything else except specify the generic type in the `map()` call

```
return ints.stream().<A>map(B::new).filter(b -> true);
```

Comment: With the inferring made by the compiler in `Stream<A> foo = ints.stream().map(B::new)`, can we still say `Stream` is invariant? Looks covariant to me.

Comment: We will still say that [generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant), because that's a fact. We can't say that "Stream is invariant", because `Stream` is an object. In this case call-site covariance is enabled with `<? extends R>`, but a generic type of `R` is still invariant.

Comment: In this case, the variance of `map` is not relevant, but rather, you see type inference at work. For `Stream<A> foo = ints.stream().map(B::new);`, the target type `Stream<A>` will make Java infer `Function<Integer,A>` for the method reference `B::new`. For the other use case, `.map(B::new).filter(b -> true)` *there is no target type for `map`*, to do the same inference. When you use `.<A>map(B::new)`, you’ll again have a target type. There is no need for a type cast.

Comment: @Holger I understand it's type inference, but are you saying if it were `Function<T, R>` instead of `Function<? super T, ? extend R>` it would still be able to infer in the same way? Because with the `filter(Predicate<? super T>`)`, the inference is gone, and based on my (limited) understanding this is thanks to the wildcard / call-site covariance, which allows the inference to succeed.

Comment: The problem is that the type inference does not work for chained method invocations. With `return ints.stream().map(B::new).filter(b -> true);`, the method’s return type provides a target type for the `filter` invocation, but not for the expression on which `filter` is invoked. There would be no difference, if there were no wildcard types in the signatures, as when you use lambda expressions, the wildcards are entirely irrelevant. The variance is only relevant for parameter expressions with a stand-alone type, i.e. references to pre-existing `Function` objects.

Comment: @Holger Hmm I see. Would you care to write a better answer for this question, or have some (near-)duplicates that would address this question in a more accurate way?

Comment: @Holger how's the answer now?

Comment: As an addendum, as a comment suggested to return `Stream<? extends A>` instead, [the Guidelines for Wildcard Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) discourage from returning types with wildcards: “*Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards*”.

Answer (score 0):

(reacting on comment but too long)

`filter()` method does not cast `Stream<A>` to `Stream<B>`, actually `map()` returns something which is assignable into both `Stream<A>` and `Stream<B>` (try it yourself - refactor map into local variable). Inference mechanism is complex and takes also the target type into account (i.e. refactored local variable or - as in your original example - the method return type, in this case the flow is broken by `filter` method).

You can change return type into `Stream<? extends A>` as Alex wrote, or add explicit upcast between original `map` and `filter`: `.map(A.class::cast)`. Frankly, I don't see any sense of either proposal at this moment.