# Are streams in Java covariant or invariant?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

This is the signature of the map function for Java streams.

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

This means that this is valid Java code:

```
class R{}
class S extends R{}

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
Stream<R> myStream = list.stream().map(integer -> new S())
```

Does the last line in the code example show that `Stream` is a covariant data type in Java? Because I've heard that it's invariant. But if it is, how come I can assign a `Stream` of `R`'s subtype to a variable declared as `Stream<R>`?

Comment: Would a consumer of a stream expecting Rs have a problem if it received Ss?

Comment: **Generics** are invariant, not "streams". [Use-site covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Use-site_variance_annotations_(wildcards)) is achieved in `map()` with the use of the `? extends R` wildcard.

Comment: My guess is it is same mechanism as with `List<Number> numbers = List.of(1, 2, 3)` (notice that we are using `List<Number>` not `List<Integer>`) where compiler can infer correct generic type used by method based on *variable* which would hold the result of generic method. In your case R can be inferred from variable used to assign result of `map(...)` call, allowing `new S()` to be treated as representation of `S` type.

Comment: I edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220995/cannot-return-stream-of-subclass-objects-after-filtering) since this is pretty much a duplicate. If there's still something unclear, leave a comment, although I don't know if I can try to explain things any better. I had to look up the correct terms to use myself.

Comment: The variance of the `map` signature is irrelevant when you use a lambda expression, as type inference for lambda expressions will always use the *bounds* of the wildcard types. What you see here, is not different to `Function<Integer, R> f = integer -> new S();`. There is no problem with a `return` statement returning a more specific object than the method’s declared return type.